# Draggable jquery function inside div positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a Jquery a script to drag images (currently only one image) around inside a div. I am currently using this code:

```
    var offset = 0,
        xPos = 0,
        yPos = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item").draggable({
        containment: '#house_wall1',

        drag: function(){
            offset = $(this).position();
            xPos = offset.left;
            yPos = offset.top;
            $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
            $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
        },

        // Find original position of dragged image.
        start: function(event, ui) {
            // Show start dragged position of image.
            var Startpos = $(this).position();
            $("div#start").text("START: \nLeft: "+ Startpos.left + "\nTop: " + Startpos.top);
        },

        // Find position where image is dropped.
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            // Show dropped position.
            var Stoppos = $(this).position();
            $("div#stop").text("STOP: \nLeft: "+ Stoppos.left + "\nTop: " + Stoppos.top);
        }
    });
});
```

My problem is not that the draggable images is not inside the div, my problem is that the positions x and y is calculated from the screen sizes and not the div. That means if you resize the screen or have a lower screen resolution, the images will in fact hold a different x and y position than a person with another resolution. How can I change the image positions to track x and y from the div margins instead of the screens size. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/)** instead of `offset()`. **[`position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/)** gives you the top/left w.r.t. to the element's parent element instead of the document top/left.

```
offset = $(this).position();
```

Comment: Like the above? In that case, I can't move the image around anymore, it is not draggable anymore

Comment: Sorry i had misunderstood you, it works correctly now, with the code above. Thanks!